# use .sfz soundfonts to render audio with WebMScore

Tags: node.js, soundfont

I'm using [WebMScore](https://github.com/LibreScore/webmscore) to render audio of music scores (it's a fork of MuseScore that runs in the browser or node).

I can successfully load my own, local .sf2 or .sf3 files, however

**Trying to load an `.sfz` soundfont throws `error 15424120`.  (And error.message is simply 'undefined'.)**

Unlike .sf2 and .sf3, which contain the sounds and instructions in a single file, the .sfz format is just a text instruction file that refers to a separate folder of samples.

The reason I need the .sfz is that I need to be able to edit the .sfz file textually and programatically without an intervening Soundfont generator.

**Is there a way to use .sfz's?  Do I need to specify Zerberus (the Musescore .sfz player)?  Do I need a different file structure?**  Please see below.

My environment is node js, with the following test case and file structure:

**File Structure**

```
Project Folder
    app.js
    testScore.mscz
    mySFZ.sfz
    samples
           one.wav
           two.wav
           etc.wav
```

**Test Case**  (Works with .sf3 , errors with .sfz)

```
const WebMscore = require('webmscore');
const fs = require('fs');

// free example scores available at https://musescore.com/openscore/scores
const name = 'testScore.mscz';
const exportedPrefix = 'exported';
const filedata = fs.readFileSync(`./${name}`);

WebMscore.ready.then(async () => {
    const score = await WebMscore.load('mscz', filedata, [], false);
    await score.setSoundFont(fs.readFileSync('./mySFZ.sfz'));
    try { fs.writeFileSync(`./${exportedPrefix}.mp3`, await score.saveAudio('mp3')); } 
    catch (err) { console.log(err) } 
    score.destroy();
});
```